# Creating JSON in python for an error message

Tags: python, json

```
import json
```

I'm trying to create a simple json error message to return if I receive a 404 error during the course of my program, but it isn't working as I anticipated.

```
error_data = '{"can_post": "error", "website": "error"}'
print json.dumps(error_data)
```

gives me:

```
"{\"can_post\": \"error\", \"website\": \"error\"}"
```

what am I doing wrong? I expected:

```
{"can_post": "error", "website": "error"}
```

I realize I could do this:

```
error_data = '{"can_post": "error", "website": "error"}'
print json.dumps(error_data)
```

Which works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are feeding `json.dumps` a string. It should be an object:

```
error_data = {"can_post": "error", "website": "error"}
print json.dumps(error_data)
```